# WCF OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, memory

I try to test performance limits on WCF service I have, My computer have 16GB memory(around 10 GB memory free during the testing)

My service is reading a file, and make a Byte array from it and send it to the client.
The service works fine on 50mb file, but when I try 100mb file, it throw exception when I create the byte array:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in Infrastructure.dll
```

byte[] myObject = new byte[file size] (the file size is around 109,372,754 bytes).

Things I tried to fix the problem:

- I find out that the max byte array size is 2GB (2,147,483,591)
- When I create new console application, with the same code, it works fine.
- Because of that reason, I think the problem is the memory allocation for the w3wp service (the service the run the WCF service in my case)
- I checked the machine.config and saw that processModel is on autoConfig, that mean my IIS should have 60% of my memory.

Anyone have any idea why I am getting that error, even I have the memory to process it?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are you doing that you need a 100mb array in iis?

Comment: My object contains a lot of data that I want to send to the client. I create a byte array from it and then I use zipping code that make it 20~30mb at the end.

Comment: But do you need to keep it all in memory at once? Does your zipping library accept a stream and you could pass it in that way?

Comment: my zipping library can work only with byte array, I just don't understand why it throw exception if I have the needed memory.